# I Have Problem with swap memory in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gparted, swap

My swap memory was `7.7` Gig and I change it to `10` Gig with `gparted`

Now When I go into `gparted` it shows me that my swap is `10 gig`
but in `gnome system monitor` shows it `2 gig` 
and in `htop` and `top` just shows swap is `2 gig`

Like this picture -->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsNdt.jpg

**Now What Should I do to see my swap 10 gig in all of them?**

Comment: You're probably using a /swapfile, instead of the 10G swap partition that you created. Please describe the EXACT steps that you used to create/prepare the 10G swap partition. Any particular reason to use a swap partition instead of a /swapfile? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid` and `free -h`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Thank you , I changed my /etc/fstab and it worked , make it as an answer , so I can Accept it @heynnema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments...

You're probably using the standard 2G /swapfile that comes with a fresh install of 20.04, instead of the carefully crafted 10G swap partition that you've created.

Decide which type of swap you wish to use.

**To stick with an enlarged /swapfile, do this...**

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=8192

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 8G swap
```

Add this line to /etc/fstab...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

**To stick with the 10G swap partition...**

`sudo blkid | grep -i swap` # identify the UUID

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` # edit the file

If it exists, remove this line...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

Locate your current swap mount, and change it to include the proper UUID, or add a line that looks similar to...

```
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx  none  swap       sw       0       0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can confirm your swap memory size using `swapon --show`.
It will show the current swap available.

After using the `fallocate` command in Linux to change the size of the swap file, make sure you mark this file as swap.

```
size = 16G // Size = 16GB (Assumed)
sudo fallocate -l $size /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

And most importantly, do enable the swap file after the allocation and marking:
`sudo swapon /swapfile`.

Comment: `dd` should be used, not `fallocate`. You're also missing other commands required to properly create a /swapfile. And edits to /etc/fstab.

Comment: The above commands worked for me, and everything is working fine.

Comment: See `man swapon` and `man mkswap` for information about fallocate creating files with "holes" in them. You also forgot `sudo chmod 600 /swapfile`, and an example of how to add /swapfile to /etc/fstab. It's just an incomplete answer. See my answer.